# Real project examples that utilize JS callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, project

I am trying to understand where we use callback functions frequently in javascript, can you please give some real project examples? I learned the concept and how to create callback functions but never seen it in real application...btw I meant using vanilla javascript not jquery etc...

Comment: well thanks for -1. if you can google out what project you can build that use callbacks please let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the type of question that Stack Overflow is for. SO is for specific questions about code. It's not for suggestions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: The simplest example of a callback is the `Array.prototype.forEach` function, it takes a callback that is called for each item in the array. Example: `[3,2,5,6,7].forEach(i => console.log(i))` In this example, the arrow function is a callback function. The main difference is that this callback is synchronous, whereas a callback is usually asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can shoe-horn callbacks in anywhere, if you really want. It's just one way of making sure things are done in sequence

```
//Triggers the function below
addToList('milk',function(result){
    console.log(result);

});

//The function that does the adding
function addToList(item,cb){
   list.push(item);
   cb(item + ' added to list');
}
```

Comment: Another definition: a way to let the caller specify an action to run at a specific point during processing.